# How to print comma separated list of character strings without quotations in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame 'output' in R listing the labels of tibbles in my workspace:

```
output
1    csv1
2    csv2
3    csv3
4    csv4
5    csv5
6    csv6
7    csv7
8    csv8
.
. 
35   csv35
```

and would like to print it as the input of a function:

```
dplyr::bind_rows(csv1,csv2,csv3...csv35)
```

(each of csv1,csv2 etc are tibbles themselves)

paste() and as.list() don't seem to work

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: do you literally want to print a string or are you trying to create this to make a call to `bind_rows()`?

Comment: sorry, title is probably misleading - I don't want to print as string but simply as csv1,csv2 with no quotations so I can use as input to bind_rows() call

Comment: Have you tried `mget`?

Comment: @CocoNewton As Ben shows in his answer (as Rui mentioned here) don't think about this problem from the point of view of creating calls by pasting strings together. You can certainly do this, but it's complicated. Instead, arrange your objects (here `csv1`, `csv2`, etc) in a list and then work with the list (either with a function like `bind_rows()` which can take a list, or by iterating over the elements of the list with `purrr::map()` and friends).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Probably* the easiest way to do what you want is to call `mget()` to create a list to pass to `bind_rows`:

```
bind_rows(mget(output[[1]]))
```

More generally, though, your procedure looks like an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern); it's easier to deal with sets of objects as lists in R, rather than generating a bunch of objects in your workspace and then figuring out how to deal with them ...

For example, if you have a character vector of CSV files,

```
csv_list <- purrr::map(csv_filenames, read_csv)
bind_rows(csv_list)
```

will work. (In fact, `purrr::map_dfr(csv_filenames, read_csv)` will do this in a single step ...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! So do you mean, instead of generating 35 different tibbles, try to put them into a single object? Or don't have 'output' as a data frame but another object?

Comment: set up your workflow so that you generate the tibbles as elements in a list of tibbles in the first place ...  (for example, if these are tibbles derived from reading in CSV files, you can use a `for` loop, or `lapply`, or `purrr::map()`, to generate them as a list)

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution with lapply so all my tibbles are in a single list. So then I can do bind_rows(list[1],list[2]), right? Which is better?

Comment: then you should be able to just do `bind_rows(your_list)` !